# jquery javascript equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use too much jquery

I want to do this with out jquery:

```
<a onclick="javascript:$(this).next().css('display', 'none')">
```

I thought it was this:

```
<a onclick="javascript:this.nextSibling.style.display = 'none'">
```

But its not.  Style returns undefined.

Let me clarify:

I want to do this:

```
<a class="errorToggle">error</a>
<div style="padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;display:none;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: <?php echo $severity; ?></p>
<p>Message:  <?php echo $message; ?></p>
<p>Filename: <?php echo $filepath; ?></p>
<p>Line Number: <?php echo $line; ?></p>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".errorToggle").click(function(){
    $(this).next().css("display", "block");
  });
</script>
```

Without jQuery BECAUSE this is a code igniter error view file that quite often will load before my header does, so I will not have access to jquery.  It doesn't need to be pretty, or well coded, just work.  This will not be used in production.

Comment: What do you mean by "too much" jQuery? If you use any at all, it's coming along for the ride, so you might as well use it. Also, if you are getting it from a CDN it's probably already cached in your visitors' browsers so there's not too much overhead.

If you mean you don't want to use it AT ALL, I sympathize. If only Netscape had given Microsoft the source code (or even just the specs) to start with, the poor dears wouldn't have had to try to reverse engineer it in order to steal it, and browser compatibility would be much better.

Comment: jQuery or no jQuery, you don't want `javascript:` at the start of your event handlers.

Comment: You also don't want event handlers in your HTML

Comment: This is a quick fix I am adding to the php error view file in code igniter.  It often will produce these errors before the header has loaded, hence, no jquery.  Too much jquery, meaning, I just don't know how to do things with regular javascript these days, not that I don't want to use jquery any more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this article:
[JavaScript nextSibling and Cross Browser Compatibility](http://blogs.creative-jar.com/post/JavaScript-nextSibling-and-Cross-Browser-Compatability.aspx)

Excerpt:

> The problem was that we were
>   referencing the 'nextSibling' of an
>   element in our JS using the onClick
>   event. In IE this worked great,
>   however in Firefox the 'nextSibling'
>   could be a line break.

You might want to iterate through the "nextSibling()" until you hit what you want.

Comment: This is WHY you use a library like jQuery -- cross browser assured same-behavior. Write once, just works.

Comment: This is also WHY many of us are crippled without these libraries and frameworks. I'm one of those as well. Hah

Comment: @bobince: Really? Any reference?

Comment: It's one of those areas that fell between the cracks in that SGML says nothing at all about DOMs (only rendering) and W3 DOM said nothing at all about parsing, until DOM Level 3 Core and LS (which IE does not claim to support). Under DOM 3 LS one is to include all text content by default, unless the element-content-whitespace parameter is set to false, in which case whitespace-only text nodes are omitted in elements that the doctype defines as containing only other elements. (Most HTML elements have mixed content and not element content anyway.)

Comment: This is finally cleared up for good by HTML5 section 3.2.5 (though of course HTML5 is not yet a complete standard).

Comment: @bobince: Thanks for the info. Very enligthening indeed.